# Push the Checkbox Value and Name in Array in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, checkbox, push

I've issues with the checkbox. I want to get the `value` and `name` field data in array format to do further processes.

**Here's Checkbox:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Honda" name="A1" value="Honda" onClick={CheckHandler} /> 
<label htmlFor="Honda" >Honda</label>
```

Now, I want to get the `name` and `value` field data in **`JSON`** or in an **`array`**

**Like this:**

```
{ name:"A1", value:"Honda" }   //I want this.
```

---

So, I've coded like this:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);


  const CheckHandler = (e) => {

    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;

  //  setCars((prev) =>
  //    cars.includes(value)
  //      ? prev.filter((cur) => cur !== value)
  //      : [...prev, {[e.target.value]:`${e.target.name}`}] 
  //  );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cars);
  }, [cars]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Honda" name="A1" value="Honda" onClick={CheckHandler}/>
      <label htmlFor="Honda">Honda</label>
      <br/>

      <input type="checkbox" id="Mustang" name="A8" value="Mustang" onClick={CheckHandler}/>
      <label htmlFor="Mustang">Mustang</label>
      <br />

      <input type="checkbox" id="Jeep" name="A12" value="Jeep" onClick={CheckHandler}/>
      <label htmlFor="Jeep">Jeep</label>
      <br />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

**MY PROBLEM**: whenever I `Tick` on checkbox It works fine, But when I `unchecked` its not returning sets from remaining items. IT's returning from all items. why ??

**Any one Knows Answer ??**

**Sandbox**  https://codesandbox.io/s/late-water-piszn

Answer (score 2):

Hi I fiddled a bit of your code and

```js
const checkHandler = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const name = e.target.name;
  setCars((prev) =>
    cars.find(ch => ch[value] === name)
      ? prev.filter((cur) => cur[value] !== name)
      : [...prev, { [e.target.value]: `${e.target.name}` }]
  );
};
```

update your method like this and it's working.

Comment: Just being a nitpick to Vishal, but ew, please change your CheckHandler function to camelcase. =)

Comment: That's actually not my function to write. I bearly fixed a small portion of it. So the name owned by the creator of this question =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated function I made for you answer

```
const CheckHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(cars);
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      if (cars[i][value] === name) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    setCars((prev) =>
      found
        ? prev.filter((cur) => cur[value] !== name)
        : [...prev, { [value]: name }]
    );
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-sunset-ssxsd?file=/src/App.js:138-548) is the sandbox